# Two animations on one activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a hirearchy like this: activityA <-> activityB <-> activityC. A is a menu, B is a list and C are details for a list item. Now i want to incorporate animations that swipe the screen from left to right or right to left, depending on which "direction" the user is going. So if he goes from activity A to activity B or B to C the screen would swipe from right to left, and if he would go from C to B or B to A the screen would swipe from left to right.

From A to B and B to C i just use an `overridePendingTransition()` and use a custom animation right after `startActivity()`, and for going backwards from C to B i do the same but in the onPause() method of the activity.

The problem i have is in the middle B activity. If i put the `overridePendingTransition()` in the `onPause()` method it will always run, no matter if the user goes from B to A or B to C, so it will always be only in one direction, even if i use a different animation when clicking a button to go to activity C. How can i check if the user pressed a listitem to get to C or if he pressed back (or something else) to go to activity A.

If it matters, the middle B activity is a FragmentActivity with a private class FragmentPagerAdapter, which serves a custom standalone adapter (for custom listview items).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this custom Animation theme to all 3 activities:

```
<style name="customAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/push_left_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/push_right_out</item>
</style>
```

push_left_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

push_right_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

Comment: This worked surprisingly well, but now the problem is that only one activity is animated. So if i want to go from A to B, B is pushed in like it should be but A just fades to black and stays in the same place (which i have no idea why). I'd like it to move alongside B, so it looks like B pushes it from the screen. The same if i go from B to A, B is animated properly but a is just displayed in the background (no fading this time).

Comment: I see that i could use OpenExit and CloseEnter in my theme, but wouldnt that produce the same problem?

Comment: YES i got it to work, i just added these two items (and modified animations):

`<item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/push_right_in</item>`

        `<item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/push_left_out</item>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overridePendingTransition()` from your `onPause()` method.

Comment: But then when i try to go from let's say B to A by clicking the back button it uses the default android animation instead of the one i want it to use.